# one svn project for two different jenkins builds (with another dependency)

Tags: java, maven, svn, jenkins, build-process

Following scenario:
Existing Jenkins project (called A) with a dependency (3D extension) with a SVN connection.
This dependency is also a Jenkins project also with a separate SVN connection.

What I want to do now:

Create another Jenkins project as reference of A w/o the 3D extension (called project B). It's absolutely necessary that I haven't got to copy project A in it's full source code / SVN.
Jenkins mustn't throw error for the project B, because it can't find the 3D extension.

What do I have to do now?

I have thought of creating another POM file and use it as parent POM for project B.
This POM doesn't include the 3D extension, but listens on the SVN connection of project A.

The project A with 3D extension is the child POM, which uses the parent POM and additionally the 3D extension.

Is it the right approach? What I didn't understand is, how Jenkins could avoid the compiling error when compiling "project B", because of the missing 3d extension.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for you is a parameterized build script

Comment: So what would a parameter be? The 3D extension? Do you have an example for this scenario mentioned above? How should I manage the build process and the developing process for this scenario?